# How to make both div height same when combining rows in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am learning Twiiter Bootstrap 3.0. I've gone thorough grid system. Basically I want to achieve structure as given below:

[image]

In the second row I've split right div in two rows as "ON" & "OFF" div, but in left side "SETPOINT" div height is not same. I want to make both div height same. Please light my path. I can do this using [JQuery (See Demo Here)](http://www.bootply.com/117729) but I want it in BOOTSTRAP 3.0 way. My Code is like this:

```
<div class="container">
<header class="row top-buffer divHeader">
<div class="col-xs-8 myBorder">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 myBorder">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 myBorder">
        <h1>Setting</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row top-buffer divBG">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <h1>Setpoint</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <h1>On</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <h1>Off</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach using CSS negative margins. Just add the `equal` class to the Bootstrap row:

```
.row.equal [class*="col-"]{
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
}

.row.equal{
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/EfOgmUPSh1

Comment: Thanks for this @Skelly... that's really great...may be I sound little foolish but why bootstrap did not give rowspan or columnspan like stuffs....or is there any other way by which we can do the same.

Comment: @bhoopendra.sahoo CSS simply does not allow for some things, or makes them prohibitively difficult or brittle.